# Apache Spark Streaming: Why is the amount of Events per Second increasing?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I found that the number of Events/sec in my Streaming Application suddenly increases (see screenshot). I made sure that the sender doesn't send more data at these moments (it always sends 800 - 900 messages per TCP). I guess it has to do with the other times below (processing / delay), but why is this shown in the Events-count graph? And can someone explain what happens there more exactly? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The number of events is directly related to the producer. This means your producer is increasing the send rate over time. At the moment of the screenshot, your mean received messages throughput was 953 msgs/s which is higher than the expected 850, taking the 800-900 range mentioned in the question as a normally distributed.

Check the producer for the particular reasons of this increase.